# Identifying source and destination with RAW FTP commands

Tags: ftp

The main idea is to upload, using RAW FTP commands, a file to a FTP server where the destination file name is different from the source file name. When issuing the commands through the FTP client in debug mode I get the following:

```
$ ftp -d ftp.server.com
Connected to ftp.server.com.
220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Name (ftp.server.com:username): user
---> USER user
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
---> PASS XXXX
230 Login successful.
---> SYST
215 UNIX Type: L8
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> passive
Passive mode on.
ftp> put sourcefile destinationfile
---> TYPE I
200 Switching to Binary mode.
---> PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (178,179,180,181,128,19).
---> STOR destinationfile
150 Ok to send data.
226 Transfer complete.
2224142 bytes sent in 1.83 seconds (1218707 bytes/s)
ftp> quit
---> QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

From what I understand from the FTP protocol the STOR command will just warn the server where to save the incoming data stream, so if I would implement a socket connection, at that point, I would just be writing into the socket file descriptor and that's pretty much it (right?).

My question is... is there a way to identify the source file name through FTP RAW commands, if I would, for instance, use a FTP client for that purpose?

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible for the server to know if the the filename is different from the name given in the `STOR` command. If so, then no.

Comment: Well not directly, but pragmatically speaking... yes, it all ends up to what you refer. After all... all the FTP commands are for client-server interaction. Thank you for the answer Amazed.